# .NET Core 2.x how to get the current active local network IPv4 address?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, ip-address, asp.net-core-2.0

On which is running the WebService. Like the one I can get in `cmd.exe > ipconfig`:
[image]

What I would like to achieve is automatic IP configuration of Kestrel, like:

```
.UseKestrel(opts => 
    { 
        opts.Listen(/*LocalIPv4ActiveAddress*/, 5000);
    })
```

So I can switch my development machines with different active network interfaces (WiFi || Ethernet) and different local network IP addresses.

Comment: I use "HttpContext.Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString()" for a MVC Application, it may be the same...

Comment: Seems that doesnt work, .NET Core doesn't provide `Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString()` part.

Comment: You could probably just use `0.0.0.0` to listen to all interfaces, if this is supported by Kestrel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// order interfaces by speed and filter out down and loopback
// take first of the remaining
var firstUpInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Speed)
    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback && c.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up);
if (firstUpInterface != null) {
    var props = firstUpInterface.GetIPProperties();
    // get first IPV4 address assigned to this interface
    var firstIpV4Address = props.UnicastAddresses
        .Where(c => c.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        .Select(c => c.Address)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the solution requires so many instructions in net core to get such simple information 

Comment: @Eugene It's a symptom of making a system overly generic. :-)

Comment: Some problems on docker enviorment, `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: The information requested in unavailable on the current platform.\n   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.LinuxNetworkInterface.get_Speed()`

Comment: Not worked in linux. have tried same code with asp.net core 3.1 application

Comment: Proof of non linux here.   https://dotnetfiddle.net/nnQ66w        Upvote for this for windows answer.

Answer (score 0):

> see the docs

First  [you will find addresses like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iphostentry.addresslist(VS.80).aspx) in the return, 
discard the ones of [family InterNetworkV6 or v4 according to your need](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.addressfamily(VS.80).aspx) and retain only the IPv4 or IPv6 ones?

> something like this

```
// Display the ScopeId property in case of IPV6 addresses.
if(curAdd.AddressFamily.ToString() == ProtocolFamily.InterNetworkV6.ToString())
  Console.WriteLine("Scope Id: " + curAdd.ScopeId.ToString());
```