# NLog - Capture host's ip address

Tags: ip, ip-address, nlog, host

I am trying to capture the host / server's ipaddress within a .NET Core 2.0 application. The ${machinename} variable captures the server's name but how do you capture the server's IP address? The name is meaningless to my team but IP address is critical.

Comment: There can be more than one IP-address: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50386894/193178 You can create your own custom layout-renderer: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer

Comment: To be sure, you aren't looking for https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-IP-Layout-Renderer?

Comment: I want the IP address (not host's name) of the machine hosting the application. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AspNet-Request-IP-Layout-Renderer will tell me the IP address of the client calling the application.

Comment: Since you are logging from the host machine, can't you set an Event-Properties variable to the ip and use it in the layout? https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer

Comment: What is the underlying property to use?

Comment: EventProperty doesn't appear to be available for .NET Core.

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas? I am surprised that the machine's IP address isn't readily available.

Comment: Anyone?? Surely this is an ask of another person?

Comment: Have updated the Wiki-page for `${event-properties}` so it shows it works on all available platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have a static IP-address, then you can do this:

```
var localIpAddress = LookupIpAddress(); // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50386894/193178
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("LocalIpAddress", localIpAddress);
```

Then you can use it target layout like this:

```
layout="${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message}|${gdc=LocalIpAddress}"
```

If your IP-address sometimes are changing, then you can setup a background-thread/timer to refresh the NLog-GDC-value.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Comment: There's nothing in the pre-defined layout properties for this?

Comment: Not right now. You are welcome to create a pullrequest (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pulls). Maybe based on the API-call  `System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses()` where it tries to prioritize Ipv4 and ignores loopback. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses

Answer (score 0):

NLog 4.6.8 has been released that include `${local-ip}`:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Local-IP-Address-Layout-Renderer