# List IP addresses in a subnet C# .net core

Tags: c#, ip

Given a string representing a network like
`58.128.0.0/16`

I want a list of all non-broadcast (not .0 or .255) within the subnet (58.128.0.1, 58.128.0.2, etc). Unfortunately all answers I can find use IPNetwork.Parse() which no longer exists in .net core 3.0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386546/net-core-2-x-how-to-get-the-current-active-local-network-ipv4-address

Comment: I don't see any relevant answer there

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a library now for this https://github.com/jsakamoto/ipaddressrange

```cs
IPAddressRange range = IPAddressRange.Parse("58.128.0.0/16");
foreach(var ip in range) {

}
```