# System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal is null on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-ad-b2c, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

So, we created this project: https://github.com/efonsecab/BlazorRestaurant

The EF Core logic for SaveChanges is extended to automatically fill the data for the auditing columns.

Logic is in the **BlazorRestaurantDbContext.partial.cs** file.

```
public partial class BlazorRestaurantDbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ValidateAndSetDefaults();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        ValidateAndSetDefaults();
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ValidateAndSetDefaults();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        ValidateAndSetDefaults();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private void ValidateAndSetDefaults()
    {
        //Check https://www.bricelam.net/2016/12/13/validation-in-efcore.html
        var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                       where e.State == EntityState.Added
                           || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                       select e.Entity;
        string ipAddresses = String.Empty;
        string assemblyFullName = String.Empty;
        string rowCretionUser = String.Empty;
        if (entities.Any(p => p is IOriginatorInfo))
        {
            ipAddresses = String.Join(",", GetCurrentHostIPv4Addresses());
            assemblyFullName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().FullName;
            if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity != null)
                rowCretionUser = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
            else
                rowCretionUser = "Unknown";
        }
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity is IOriginatorInfo)
            {
                IOriginatorInfo entityWithOriginator = entity as IOriginatorInfo;
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityWithOriginator.SourceApplication))
                {
                    entityWithOriginator.SourceApplication = assemblyFullName;
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityWithOriginator.OriginatorIpaddress))
                {
                    entityWithOriginator.OriginatorIpaddress = ipAddresses;
                }
                if (entityWithOriginator.RowCreationDateTime == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
                {
                    entityWithOriginator.RowCreationDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                }
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityWithOriginator.RowCreationUser))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        entityWithOriginator.RowCreationUser = rowCretionUser;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        entityWithOriginator.RowCreationUser = "Unknown";
                    }
                }
            }
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
            Validator.ValidateObject(
                entity,
                validationContext,
                validateAllProperties: true);
        }
    }

    public static List<string> GetCurrentHostIPv4Addresses()
    {
        //Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386546/net-core-2-x-how-to-get-the-current-active-local-network-ipv4-address
        // order interfaces by speed and filter out down and loopback
        // take first of the remaining
        var allUpInterfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.Speed)
            .Where(c => c.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback &&
            c.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up).ToList();
        List<string> lstIps = new();
        if (allUpInterfaces != null && allUpInterfaces.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var singleUpInterface in allUpInterfaces)
            {
                var props = singleUpInterface.GetIPProperties();
                // get first IPV4 address assigned to this interface
                var allIpV4Address = props.UnicastAddresses
                    .Where(c => c.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    .Select(c => c.Address)
                    .ToList();
                allIpV4Address.ForEach((IpV4Address) =>
                {
                    lstIps.Add(IpV4Address.ToString());
                });
            }
        }

        return lstIps;
    }
}
```

We have used this same code in other apps and works, great.
In this specific app, however, the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal and ClaimsPrincipal.Current, are null, when the ValidateAndSetDefaults method is executed.

Even tried the following

```
            services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
            JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
                options.Events.OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = context.Principal;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                options.SaveToken = true;
            });
```

The context.Principal does have all the data we need at this point, but we still get null reading the Thread's CurrenPrincipal object.

Any ideas how to fix it, so we can properly get the Authenticated User information in the code above, it exists in context.Principal, it is just not accesible later in the SaveChanges for EF Core.

Comment: Do you  think issue is with connection to database or values not being returned from query?  did you check the connection string?  Are you using same server and working code?  You are saying "get the Authenticated User information".  Sound like you have a TLS issue.  Microsoft made changes last year disabling TLS 1.0 and 1.1 so now you have to use TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3. Do you have latest version of vendors API?  Most vendors upgraded to work with TLS 1.2 or 1.3  Are you working with Core?  Do you have latest version of Mobile device Kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using Dependency Injection along with HttpContextAccesor
https://github.com/efonsecab/BlazorRestaurant/blob/main/src/BlazorRestaurantSln/BlazorRestaurant.DataAccess/Data/BlazorRestaurantDbContext.partial.cs

Comment: For those who came to this post but with a Console app in .NET Core, you need to set the Windows principal policy, as mentioned in this [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29151). example: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);